# Why this ORMLite query is not working?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, ormlite

I have a select with multiple columns:

```
select columnA,AVG(columnB),AVG(columnC),AVG(columnD),AVG(columnE)...
```

columnA is an Integer and all the others are Double. Here is how i initialize the `GenericRawResults` object:

```
GenericRawResults<Object[]>rawResults = dao.queryRaw(
    "SELECT columnA,AVG(columnB),AVG(columnC),AVG(columnD),AVG(columnE)...",
    new DataType[]{DataType.INTEGER,DataType.DOUBLE,DataType.DOUBLE,...});
```

When I run a for statement...

```
for(Object[] result: rawResults) {
     //some code here
 }
```

I get this Exception:

> Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.j256.ormlite.stmt.SelectIterator.hasNext()' on a null object reference

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: When you are providing information about a problem, always provide the _entire_ exception?

Comment: `rawResults` is null ...

Comment: @PeterMmm yes i know, but I don't why!